# Any way to shrink JVM heap running Coldfusion 9 once allocated?

Tags: coldfusion, jvm, heap-memory, coldfusion-9

We have our JVM set for our CF9 server to allocate a max of 2GB of heap space.  Normally, it only allocates around 750MB to 1GB, and we really only use around 500MB of that.

A rogue script just got fired off, and it ended up hogging the heap space, and so the JVM had allocated the full 2GB limit.  Now, we are back to running at our normal pace, using only 500MB of the 2GB allocated, and our server is now at 90% memory usage.

Is there any setting we can use that will shrink the max heap space for the JVM when it no longer needs that much allocated?  Or, will this always stay like this until the next reboot?  Just wondering because we only have 10% left of our memory on the server for "wiggle" room...

Thanks!

EDIT:

Just to clarify a bit more.  We set our initial heap size to 750MB by setting the JVM argument "-Xms750m".  Our max heap size it set by the JVM argument "-Xmx2048M".  Before the script ran, our allocated heap size was around 1GB.  Of this 1GB, we were only really using on average 500MB.  After the script ran, the heap was pushed to its limit, and so now there is 2GB of pre-allocated heap space that we are again only using 500MB of on average.

So, this has put Windows at recording 90% or more of memory usage.  There is probably at least a GB or a bit more that *could* be released by the JVM as it is never used, however, we don't know how to force that to happen, or if there is some kind of JVM setting to do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a full GC and it will shrink the heap. With a minimum of 750 megs the OS can "reclaim" that memory (and you really don't have to do anything). However, if you are memory constrained you may have contention issues in the future so you might consider tuning a little better. I typically set minimum and maximum the same so that I do not have to think about this issue to closely. Anyway - here's a script that may help you:

```
<Cfset runtime = CreateObject("java","java.lang.Runtime").getRuntime()>

<cfset fm = runtime.freememory()/>

<Cfset fm = int((fm/1024)/1024)/>

<cfset usedmem = 1270-fm/>
<cfoutput><br>
<br>
Free: #fm# megs<br>
Used: #usedmem# megs<br>
</cfoutput>

<cfset obj = createObject("java","java.lang.System")/>

    <cfset obj.gc()/>

    <cfset obj.runFinalization()/>
```

The first part of the script shows free memory and the second part runs a full garbage collection (a full pause as well so this will likely be noticeable depending on your traffic and hardware).

Good luck :)

Comment: We are already running garbage collection.  Like I said, we are only running at like 500MB used heap, but the JVM has allocated 2GB (we set an initial heap size on JVM startup of like 750MB and set the max heap at 2GB).  So, the heap usage is fine, it's just that now there is around 1.5GB of extra JVM heap space sitting there that is not used, which is 1.5GB more memory that Windows could be using for other stuff.  Would that script simply clean out the heap, or actually force the JVM to release part of its allocated heap and give it back to Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If the heap is back to reporting at 500 meg again, then there are a few possibilities as to what's going on:

The memory is used in PermGen. Perm doesn't get cleared down by the Garbage Collector in the same way (if at all). If you can run JPS or JVisualVM from the JDK on the server then you may be able to get a handle on where the memory is used, as they report on Perm Gen usage.

The other possibility is that the OS measure you're using is reflecting the max memory used by the process, not the current memory. I'm not an expert here, but it might be useful if you can post exactly which metrics you're using to show memory usage.

I suppose that the JVM may not be releasing memory it's Garbage Collected back to the OS, although I've not seen that happen myself.

When your rogue script ran, you say it took the whole heap before crashing. Did it die with an OutOfMemoryException? If you scan the exception-log, is there anything written there about which threads crashed? Generally, once your JVM has experienced an OOM, you should probably restart, as you can't tell whether any application state has been corrupted.

Comment: Barny - probably more of a panic attack. Sometimes that memory hangs around until the OS or something else charges to reclaim it.

Comment: No, I don't think an outOfMemory error occurred.  Everything stills seems to be running fine.  We have experienced our fair share of memory issues on our old server, from dealing with the PermGen to running out of JVM stack space due to the confines of 32-bit Coldfusion.  This is simply a question of allowing the JVM to release any pre-allocated heap space that it is not using and giving it back to Windows (as we have more than a GB of it sitting around not being used).